# updated nested property without having multiple loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One problem I face is I always repeat myself when manipulating array or object in `JavaScript`. We are fading away from the `jQuery` age where we can simply take and amend the stat into or from the `DOM`.

Take this nested array of object for instance

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "item1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "item2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In order to change the `checked` property of `item2` I have to do 2 loops

```
const newData = data.map(o=>{
  return {
    ...o,
    data: o.data.map(o2=>{
     if(o2.name === 'item2'){
       return{
         ...o2,
         'checked': true
       }
     }
     return o2
   })
  }
})
```

Any better alternative for this problem?

Comment: It's always best to structure your data as per your needs, For example it is not always that you need array to store the data, plain objects can also serve your purpose.

Comment: if your data is an array inside an array, you should do a `nested-loop` because the solution is an `O(n^2)` Complexity. there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @VipinKumar if it's simple thing then the structure is simple but in some case the structure 'have' to be complicated.

Comment: There's a number of ways to solve this problem. A ubiquitous approach in pure functional programming languages (where they're forced to reconstitute the data structure like this all the time) is to use lenses. There's more fun things you can do, like exploiting the fact that each level of nesting is actually a functor. I'll write out some examples as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to realize that each level of nesting in your complicated data structure is a "functor" (beyond the scope of this answer to explain it, but there's lots of good explanations online).

The functors-101 explanation is that it is a generalization of the concept of "mappability", so that you can map over arrays, objects, observables, all kinds of kooky things, while preserving their structure.

Anyway, given that your data structure is a functor embedded in a functor embedded in a functor, you can map over the deepest level by simply composing the `map` function with itself as many times as there are levels in your nested-functors structure.

E.g. in your case you could use `map3` to do:

```
const result = map3(x => x.name === "item2" ? { ...x, checked: true } : x)(data)
```

Here is a full JS implementation (I implemented the FP library bits inline instead of using a dependency to elucidate what's going on):

```js
// FP utils (you can use a library like Sanctuary or Ramda to get these)
const merge = (o1, o2) => ({
  ...o1,
  ...o2
})
const compose = fns => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)))

const mapArr = f => a => a.map(f)
const mapObj = f => o =>
  Object.keys(o)
    .map(k => ({
      [k]: f(o[k])
    }))
    .reduce(merge)
const mapImpls = new Map([[Object, mapObj], [Array, mapArr]])

const map = f => x => mapImpls.get(x.constructor)(f)(x)

const map2 = compose([map, map])
const map3 = compose([map, map, map])
const map4 = compose([map, map, map, map])
// ...

// Your code
const data = [
  {
    data: [
      {
        name: "item1",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: "item2",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
const projection = x =>
  x.name === "item2"
    ? {
        ...x,
        checked: true
      }
    : x
const result = map3(projection)(data)
console.log(result)
```

As far as I know, the first person to give a name to this pattern is [Conal Elliott](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators), in his blog post on "semantic editor combinators".

Comment: @Rajesh Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks, I hadn't used that feature before. Anything in particular you don't understand?

Comment: That was a pun. ;-) I figured after reading it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you structure your state ex. same data if represented this way

```
{
 item1 : {name:"item1" ,checked:true} 
 ...
}
```

may lead to a simple operation without loop , or if you have id's you can use those as well. 
Knowing  normalizr can be really helpful for structuring your state [link](http://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).

Comment: Agreed on the second point, normalizr help but you're showing me an object, I need array of object.

Comment: you can get the array of objects from Object.values

Answer (score 0):

```
let your_data = [
    {
    "data": [
        {
        "name": "item1",
        "checked": false
        },
        {
        "name": "item2",
        "checked": false
        }
    ]
    }
]
let data = [...your_data];
let index = 0, mod = 0, flag = false, rew_array = [];
while(index < data.length){
    if(!flag){
        new_array[index] = {...data[index]};
        mod = data[index].data.length;
        index = 0;
        flag = true;
    }else{
        let __index = new_array.length-1;
        let array = new_array[__index].data;
        if(array[index].name === 'item2'){
            array[index] = {
                ...array[index],
                'checked': true
            }
        }
        if(index > mod) {
            index = new_array.length;
            mod = 0;
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    index++;
}

console.log(data);
```

since you know the structure of your data already, you could run it through a single while loop, where the index is always changing based on some offset `mod`. In this example, i'm using a `flag` to tell me when i am checking for the outer data, or the inner data. and change the index accordingly.

Although, I must admit, there is no getting around the fact that you will still, ultimately be doing the same amount of iterations.

Comment: omg how this solution is more simple and readable to my solution?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you define readable. Some think having the code flattened helps them to understand it better. 

I assumed thats what you were going for, because you solution is quite terse already. If you want to make it simpler, you could construct you object into a proxy perhaps, and create an api for easily traversing it.

Comment: Or perhaps separating each array traversal into two seperate method calls, and abstract it away.